# ionic 3 infinite scroll

Tags: arrays, loops, ionic3

This is my code for infinite loop, it work well, posts are loaded, but instead of continuing the articles in a row I see the last articles from the loop because loop is made every time. Some tips how push data to be countinuing loop.

```
export class HomePage {
posts: any;
more: any;
postlen: number = 0;
imglink: string = "http://blog.bax/img/";

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, 
public http: Http) {
  let url = "http://blog.bax/api/blog";
  this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
     console.log(this.posts = data);
  });
}

openPage(post:any) {
  this.navCtrl.push('NewsPage', {post: post});
}

openPageMore(morepost:any) {
 this.navCtrl.push('NewsPage', {morepost: morepost});
}

loadMore(infiniteScroll:any) {
setTimeout(() => {
 this.postlen+=20;
  let urlmore = "http://blog.bax/api/indexmore/" + this.postlen;
  console.log(urlmore)
  this.http.get(urlmore).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
    this.more = data;
  });
  infiniteScroll.complete();
 }, 500);
 }
  }

  home.html

   <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let post of posts" (click)="openPage(post)">
    <ion-thumbnail item-start>
        <img src="{{imglink}}{{post.image}}">
    </ion-thumbnail>
      <h2> {{ post.title }}</h2>
      <p> {{ post.excerpt }}</p>
   </ion-item>
   <ion-item *ngFor="let post of more" (click)="openPage(post)">
    <ion-thumbnail item-start>
        <img src="{{imglink}}{{post.image}}">
    </ion-thumbnail>
      <h2> {{ post.title }}</h2>
      <p> {{ post.excerpt }}</p>
   </ion-item>
   <ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="loadMore($event)">
    <ion-infinite-scroll-content></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
    </ion-infinite-scroll>

   </ion-list>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace these two lines

Replace `more: any;` with `more: any = []`

And `this.more = data;` with `this.more = this.more.concate(data);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the following code,

```
    <ion-item *ngFor="let post of posts" (click)="openPage(post)">
    <ion-thumbnail item-start>
        <img src="{{imglink}}{{post.image}}">
    </ion-thumbnail>
      <h2> {{ post.title }}</h2>
      <p> {{ post.excerpt }}</p>
   </ion-item>
   <ion-item *ngFor="let post of more" (click)="openPage(post)">
    <ion-thumbnail item-start>
        <img src="{{imglink}}{{post.image}}">
    </ion-thumbnail>
      <h2> {{ post.title }}</h2>
      <p> {{ post.excerpt }}</p>
   </ion-item>
```

Replace with this,

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let post of more" (click)="openPage(post)">
    <ion-thumbnail item-start>
        <img src="{{imglink}}{{post.image}}">
    </ion-thumbnail>
    <h2> {{ post.title }}</h2>
    <p> {{ post.excerpt }}</p>
</ion-item>
```

Remove the code from your constructor. You are repeating the code again, which is not a good practice when you can reuse. Create a function `ionViewDidEnter()` or `ionViewWillEnter()` to place the code instead of the constructor, which is provided by ionic,

```
ionViewDidEnter(){
    this.loadMore();
}

loadMore(infiniteScroll:any) {
   setTimeout(() => {
       let urlmore = "http://blog.bax/api/indexmore/" + this.postlen;
       this.http.get(urlmore).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
          this.more.concat(data);
       });
       this.postlen+=20;
       if(typeof(infiniteScroll) != 'undefined')
           infiniteScroll.complete();
       }, 500);
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer, i have issue load more is not defined

Comment: Updated the answer. Have to enter `this.loadMore()`

Comment: thanks, it works, i need change line this.posts = this.posts.concat(data), api is faster when is in constructor?